# Cross-site request forgery validation failed. The "state" param from the URL and session do not match Error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Facebook PHP-SDK to allow for users to login via Facebook. However I see to keep getting this cross-site request forgery error which i can't seem to resolve. My app has been setup correctly however the State and Sesison State keys never match. I've created a FBlink.class which handles the login and the code is as follows:

```
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    require_once __DIR__ . '/src/Facebook/autoload.php';
    $fb = new app\src\Facebook\Facebook([
      'app_id' => '*', //(Ive hidden this info)
      'app_secret' => '*',
      'default_graph_version' => '*',
      ]);

    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    $permissions = ['email']; // optional

        try {
            if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
                $accessToken = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];
            } else {
                $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
            }
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
            // When Graph returns an error
            echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
            // When validation fails or other local issues
            echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
         }
        if (isset($accessToken)) {
            if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
                $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
            } else {
                // getting short-lived access token
                $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
                // OAuth 2.0 client handler
                $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();
                // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
                $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
                $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $longLivedAccessToken;
                // setting default access token to be used in script
                $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
            }
            // redirect the user back to the same page if it has "code" GET variable
            if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
                header('Location: ./');
            }
            // getting basic info about user
            try {
                $profile_request = $fb->get('/me?fields=name,first_name,last_name,email');
                $profile = $profile_request->getGraphNode()->asArray();
                print_r($profile);

            } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
                // When Graph returns an error
                echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
                session_destroy();
                // redirecting user back to app login page
                header("Location: ./");
                exit;
            } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
                // When validation fails or other local issues
                echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
                exit;
            }

            // printing $profile array on the screen which holds the basic info about user
            // Now you can redirect to another page and use the access token from $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']
        } else {
            // replace your website URL same as added in the developers.facebook.com/apps e.g. if you used http instead of https and you used non-www version or www version of your website then you must add the same here
            $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('**', $permissions);
            echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
        }
```

I'm simply including this file into my index.php to for now run. The validate CSRF function is as follows:

```
protected function validateCsrf()
    {
        $state = $this->getState();
        $savedState = $this->persistentDataHandler->get('state');
        echo 'STATE: '. $state;
        echo 'SAVED STATE: '. $savedState;

        if (!$state || !$savedState) {
            throw new FacebookSDKException('Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required param "state" missing.');
        }

        $savedLen = strlen($savedState);
        $givenLen = strlen($state);

        if ($savedLen !== $givenLen) {
            throw new FacebookSDKException('Cross-site request forgery validation failed. The "state" param from the URL and session do not match.');
        }

        $result = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $savedLen; $i++) {
            $result |= ord($state[$i]) ^ ord($savedState[$i]);
        }

        if ($result !== 0) {
            throw new FacebookSDKException('Cross-site request forgery validation failed. The "state" param from the URL and session do not match.');
        }
    }
```

The error i'm receiving is:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'app\src\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException' with message 'Cross-site request forgery validation failed. The "state" param from the URL and session do not match.' in /var/www/html/app/src/Facebook/Helpers/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php:263 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/app/src/Facebook/Helpers/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php(225): app\src\Facebook\Helpers\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper->validateCsrf() #1 /var/www/html/app/FBlink.php(21): app\src\Facebook\Helpers\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper->getAccessToken() #2 /var/www/html/index.php(7): require_once('/var/www/html/a...') #3 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/app/src/Facebook/Helpers/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php on line 263

Can anyone point out to me as to why this may be happening? If there is anymore code required, i'm happy to add some more. 
Thanks

Comment: A common issue is forgetting to put `session_start()` at the top of all scripts involved. Have you done that? Also, which of the two exceptions in your code is exactly throwing?

Comment: yeah it was as exactly as you said. I had changed my auto loader and not included session_start().